# Check if cookie expired in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I had developed an API Rest for an iPhone Game and it works properly. But I have a problem in iPhone that in each Response I had to check if session expired. I think that it is not so good, because I am copying the same piece of code on every response handler.

I think that I could make a helper or wrapper class for checking if session expire and if it happens, it will tries to get new session cookie.

I want to know if exist a native or better way to check expiration time session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConnection should handle cookies for you.  If your cookie has expired, on the next call you make you should get a 401 response.

Depending on how you implemented your calls you should have a method such as:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

response.statuscode will be 401 if the cookie is expired.  From here you can do the necessary re-validation that your app requires.

Comment: It's right, the problem is that the cookie expired, I need to get new one but I don't want to lose the request which generated 403 status code, is it clear? So I think that I need to make a queue to store request and if it response properly it will be deleted if not, it will sending again.